# Access VBA SQL: Find Max Date and retrieve row ID

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, maxdate

I'm using MS-Access 2007 with linked MS-SQL db with 2 tables.

One table is the inventory details, the other is the inventory's track, tracking each inventory's status (by ID) on a specific date.

I need to retrieve the `TrackID` for each `InvenotryID` by the max Date value, so I can get the latest status of each inventory item.

```
Inventory table: ID, Details, etc.

Track table: ID, Inventory (ID), TDate, Status, Branch.
```

Track table example:

```
   ID | Inv. | TDate | Status   
   332|    4 | 02/03 | free   
   342|    6 | 02/12 | working   
   346|    4 | 02/09 | working   
   347|    7 | 02/11 | repairs   
   349|    5 | 02/05 | repairs   
   352|    6 | 02/13 | free   
   355|    5 | 01/28 | working   
   356|    7 | 02/14 | free
```

the query should fetch:

```
   TrackID | Inv. | TDate | Status   
   346     | 4    | 02/09 | working   
   355     | 6    | 02/13 | free   
   356     | 7    | 02/14 | free   
   349     | 5    | 02/05 | repairs
```

note: `TrackID` is not necessarily the maximum value of the field due to non linear status registrations.

Due to my lack on SQL, I couldn't create a query that can manifest that idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
SELECT test.ID, test.Inv, test.TDate, test.Status
FROM test INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT test.Inv, Max(test.TDate) AS MaxOfTDate
    FROM test
    GROUP BY test.Inv)  AS q 
ON (test.TDate = q.MaxOfTDate) AND (test.Inv = q.Inv)
GROUP BY test.ID, test.Inv, test.TDate, test.Status;
```

Where test is the name of your table.

Comment: wow, Remou, thanx a lot.
complicated, short, and works like a charm :)